# Conditional return value bug fixed with a useless printf call

Tags: c, debugging

I was trying to write a simple function for collision detection for my simple game (school project) and couldn't get a proper return value out of it until I added a meaningless `printf` line (initially it was intended to assist in debugging ) and it all worked somehow. I wonder what could that bug be? and how I can fix it with a more "proper" way. Thanks.

Here is my function (Variable "rect" (rectangle)is a standard SDL struct that has 4 integer members representing it's height, width and it's corner's x and y):

```c
bool collision(SDL_Rect *rect1, SDL_Rect *rect2) {
    //chekcs to see if rect2 is totally outside of boundaries of rect1
    static bool collided;
    if (rect1->y > rect2->y + rect2->h) {
        printf("");
        collided = false;
        return collided;
    }
    if (rect1->y + rect1->h < rect2->y) {
        printf("");
        collided = false;
        return collided;
    }
    if (rect1->x > rect2->x + rect2->w) {
        printf("");
        collided = false;
        return collided;
    }   
    if (rect1->x + rect1->w < rect2->x) {
        printf("");
        collided = false;
        return collided;
    }
    //returns 1 if none of above is true

    collided = 1;
    return collided;
}
```

Edit:
I used static bool because I was trying to get Visual studio to display the boolean variable's value in watch window even when it (the variable) was outside of scope, it didn't work and I forgot to remove static. The problem is there whether I use static or not however.

Edit 2:
Here is the function that is calling the function above (I know digonalMovement needs a small fix to make the speed slower on both directions when moving diagonally (currently only 1 of them becomes slower), but this shouldn't have anything to do with the problem in hand):

```
void player_movement_calc(int player_nr, SDL_Rect char_rects[], Char character[]) {
    // determine velocity
    character[player_nr].x_vel = character[player_nr].y_vel = 0;
    bool collided = collision(&char_rects[0], &char_rects[2]);

    bool digonalMovement = 0;
    if (character[player_nr].up && !character[player_nr].down) {    
        if (digonalMovement)
            character[player_nr].y_vel = -SPEED * 0.86; //multiplying by sin(45)
        else {
            character[player_nr].y_vel = -SPEED;
        }
        digonalMovement = 1;
        if (collided)
            character[player_nr].y_vel -= 2 * character[player_nr].y_vel;
    }
    if (character[player_nr].down && !character[player_nr].up) {
        if (digonalMovement)
            character[player_nr].y_vel = SPEED * 0.86;
        else {
            character[player_nr].y_vel = SPEED;
        }
        digonalMovement = 1;
        if (collided)
            character[player_nr].y_vel -= 2 * character[player_nr].y_vel;
    }
    if (character[player_nr].left && !character[player_nr].right) {
        if (digonalMovement)
            character[player_nr].x_vel = -SPEED * 0.86;
        else {
            character[player_nr].x_vel = -SPEED;
        }
        digonalMovement = 1;
        if (collided)
            character[player_nr].y_vel -= 2 * character[player_nr].y_vel;
    }
    if (character[player_nr].right && !character[player_nr].left) {
        if (digonalMovement)
            character[player_nr].x_vel = SPEED * 0.86;
        else {
            character[player_nr].x_vel = SPEED;
        }
        digonalMovement = 1;
        if (collided)
            character[player_nr].y_vel -= 2 * character[player_nr].y_vel;
    }
    //clears diagonalMovement to make it false for next fram
    digonalMovement = 0;

    // update positions
    character[player_nr].x_pos += character[player_nr].x_vel / 60;
    character[player_nr].y_pos += character[player_nr].y_vel / 60;

    // collision detection with bounds
    if (character[player_nr].x_pos <= 0)
        character[player_nr].x_pos = 0;
    if (character[player_nr].y_pos <= 0)
        character[player_nr].y_pos = 0;
    if (character[player_nr].x_pos >= WINDOW_WIDTH - char_rects[player_nr].w)
        character[player_nr].x_pos = WINDOW_WIDTH - char_rects[player_nr].w;
    if (character[player_nr].y_pos >= WINDOW_HEIGHT - char_rects[player_nr].h)
        character[player_nr].y_pos = WINDOW_HEIGHT - char_rects[player_nr].h;

    // set the positions in the struct 
    char_rects[player_nr].y = (int)character[player_nr].y_pos;
    char_rects[player_nr].x = (int)character[player_nr].x_pos;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `static bool` for what's effectively a throw-away variable? Just `return false` instead.

Comment: that's a clear sign of _undefined behaviour_. But this code is probably not at fault. The caller is.

Comment: I used static bool because I was trying to get Visual studio to display the boolean variable's value in watch window even when the variable was outside of scope, it didn't work and I forgot to remove static. The problem is there whether I use static or not however.

Comment: An undefined behavior. How could I troubleshoot and debug such a thing?

Comment: You are not *using* the result of `collision()` anywhere in the code you have shown. A reasonable compiler will optimize out a computation if its result is unneeded.

Comment: I removed`collision` calls later and forgot to add them back before posting the question. I have added them back now anyway, and I apologize for the inconvenience caused by my carelessness.

Answer (score 1):

In the `player_movement_calc()` function, you have `collision(&char_rects[0], &char_rects[2])`. It seems you should be comparing the rectangles of the players with

```
    bool collided = collision(&char_rects[0], &char_rects[1]);
```

You may be reading beyond the end of the `char_rects` array, causing undefined behavior. Any side effects caused by `printf`, such as allocating memory for its own purpose or the the `stdout` buffer might change the behavior of the program, for example by making the memory accessed beyond the end of the array readable, hence removing the crash and hiding the bug.

Another potential explanation is the call to `collision` might be omitted by the compiler if its result is unused and if the function `collision` has no side effects. Without the `static` and the `printf`, the function has no side effect (apart from the crash caused by reading beyond the end of the array which is undefined behavior anyway). Changing the `static` value may be considered useless by the compiler since this variable is not used anywhere and not defined `volatile`. `printf` has side effects, so calling it makes `collision` unpure, hence the call cannot be elided.

It is always difficult to try and make sense of undefined behavior. When debugging, you should first disable all optimizations. The bug is probably visible without the `printf` with optimizations disabled and tracing the code and watching local variables should be much easier with unoptimised code.

Once you have a reproducible crash bug in a debug build, just use the debugger to show you where it happens. Crash bugs should be easy to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact I removed the collision function call later and forgot to add them back before posting the question. I have added them back now anyway, and I apologize for the inconvenience caused by my carelessness.

Comment: Regarding that I might be reading beyond the end of char_rect array, I made sure that it wasn't happening.

Comment: Do you still have the crash with optimisations disabled?

Comment: The program didn't crash but the function collision randomly returns true even if one of the condition in its body (that are followed by return false statement) are met. If I add the aforementioned printf calls however, it works flawlessly. And if you are referring to optimization option that is found under C/C++ in "project properties" , this was turned off by default.

Comment: Is the second argument `&char_rects[2]`or should it be `&char_rects[1]`?

Comment: It was char_rects[1] initially, I created rect[2] after I found the bug hoping something was wrong with char_rects[1], but turned out it did  not have something to do with it.

Comment: @Ramy670: how do you allocate `char_rects` and the other arguments passed to `player_movement_calc`?

Comment: I do not manually allocate memory, I just define the variable and initiate it or pass it to a function that would. Do we need to manually allocate memory in a simple program like that?

Comment: @Ramy670: how do you define these variables? Can you post the code that calls `player_movement_calc()`?